# SQL - Pulling Calculated Date Fields with Case Statement in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, case

I have a table that stores a series of information on projects. A project has an id, a status, and the date the project reached that particular status.

I am concerned with two statuses: closed and completed. As such, there are two date fields in the project table, date_closed and date_completed. Projects are completed before they are closed.

What I'm trying to do is get a count of project records that have been completed OR closed within the past 30 days. I thus need to calculate completed projects on the date_completed field, and closed projects on the date_closed field, both with a 30-day restriction.

Data looks something like this (today's date is March 8th, 2017)

```
id | status    | date_completed | date_closed
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1    completed   March-1-2017     NULL
2    completed   Jan-1-2017       NULL
3    closed      Dec-1-2016       March-1-2017
4    closed      Dec-1-2016       March-1-2017
5    closed      Dec-1-2016       Jan-1-2017
```

The result I'm looking for is the number "3" because there were three projects that have been completed or closed in the past 30 days (id's 1, 3 and 4).

I'm aware that the date calculation is something like

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, CURDATE(),date_completed/date_closed) <= 30
```

however, I'm not sure how to select the appropriate date field based on the project status. I'm almost certain there needs to be a case statement here, but the requirements for DATEDIFF are throwing me off.

How can I use the appropriate date fields in the DATEDIFF clause (or some other date calculation function) based off of each project's status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `date_closed` when it is not null, and the `date_completed` when `date_closed` is null, then:

```
where coalesce(date_closed,date_completed) >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
```

Or to check based on `status` using `or`:

```
where (
      ([status] = 'completed' and date_completed >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate()))
      or 
      ([status] = 'closed' and date_closed >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate()))
      )
```

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Based on my experience so far, my projection is never. But we can always hope! [xkcd PSA ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/). At least the ones here can't be misinterpreted.   `yyyy-dd-mm` are the ones that are particularly tricky. Especially when they are only in the first 12 days of the month.

Comment: Just a pet peeve of mine  :)

Comment: I think SqlZim's answer(s) is (are) good, but I'm nervous about assumptions as to how those status and dates work. For example is a closure always after a completion? Even if the project is reopened? And  relatedly, if a project were reopened would the dates be removed or just the status changed?

Comment: Sorry for the poorly formatted dates, was just looking for some pseudo-data to get my point across. A closure is always after a completion. Project reopening isn't relevant for what I'm trying to do, the closed/completion data would remain consistent. I appreciate everyone's help and feedback!